# Django Get Foreign key entire objects rather than just id(primary key)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-queryset

I have following Models in my Django project.

```
class State(models.Model):
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    state_code = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

class District(models.Model):
    district_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    district_code = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    state_obj = models.ForeignKey(State)
```

I want to populate list of districts along with state_obj and send it to front end.
I am using serialize and trying

```
serializers.serialize("json", District.objects.all())
```

and getting result in following format

```
{"fields": {"state_obj": 23, "district_name": "NANDURBAR", "district_code": "NANDURBAR"}, "model": "adaxial_core.district", "pk": 665}
```

Is it possible in django to get state_obj entire objects rather than id.

Output I am expecting is like.

```
{"fields": {"state_obj": {id:1,state_name:'X',state_code:'Y'}, "district_name": "NANDURBAR", "district_code": "NANDURBAR"}, "model": "adaxial_core.district", "pk": 665}
```

Want to try to do this without applying an extra loop over the result-set.

is there a way to do same

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible and it was addressed (and turned down) in a [Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4656) only recently.  If a dependency is an option for your use case, then using serializers from Django Rest Framework (or tastypie, which I've never used) may be fine. Otherwise I think you'll have do this in code.

Here is a quote from the [last comment](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4656#comment:31) on that issue:

> Unless theres a more fundamental addressing of the serialization API,
>   aimed at making it *generally* usable and extendable for Web APIs I
>   don't see any value in pushing the scope of the serializers as they
>   now stand. Right now the use case for them should be for fixture
>   loading and saving and nothing else. There are better tools out there
>   for generally extendable serialization schemes (REST framework,
>   tastypie, etc).

Django's [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) helps avoiding an additional SQL hit, so at least that would be a bit of a performance improvement.